# how to get contents of a webpage that needs authentication ? Already tried file_get_contents, fopen and cURL. none of them works

Tags: php, curl, file-get-contents

I want to parse contents of a page from my PHP website.  For instance, the remote website may be http://admin.rankedgaming.com .

I tried everything available on web to solve this issue, but I can't get contents of this specific page:

http://admin.rankedgaming.com/commands/banhistory/bans.php?m=0&var=ihatepoints

Tried passing cookies with `file_get_contents` and copied cURL headers from my browser and embedded it inside my php file without any luck. It will always show login page when accessing with cURL or file_get_contents. But It does work on my browser normally. What is preventing me from accessing it?

for authentication purposes, dummy id pass are:

```
user = ihatepoints
pass = ihate
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Have a go using Curl:

```
$ch = curl_init($host);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "ihatepoints:ihate");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
$return = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

echo $return;
```